# I have a button that when clicks it opens the link in the same page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need the code to make it a pop-up in a different window.

Here is the code that is there if you could please tell me what code needs to be added that would help

```
<p>
    <a class="btn" 
       onclick="link" 
       href="http://sizechartcms.finntack.com/?cat=competition&amp;id=32086&amp;lang=en_US">
        Size Chart
    </a>
</p>
```

Comment: There is still no code to go by. What you're thinking of could either be a javascript modal or an entirely new page which could be activated by adding _blank to a hyperlink's target

Answer (score 0):

Add `target=_blank` to open a new window:

```
<a target=_blank class="btn" href="http://sizechartcms.finntack.com/?cat=competition&amp;id=32086&amp;lang=en_US">Size Chart</a>
```

And remove `onclick="link"`

Answer (score 0):

If you want something to show up in a new tab, you need to add target="_blank" into the a tag like so:

```
<a target="_blank">
```